# ggplot2 scale_fill_grey for boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a box plot of shell lengths, with breakage (yes/no) on the x axis and 2 facets of different species (using the `facet_grid` function).
I want the species (the two separate facets) to be different shades (preferably one white and the other grey) but the `scale_fill_grey` function doesn't seem to be doing anything.

This is the code I'm using:

```
bp <- ggplot(pond2, aes(x=Breakage,y=Length)) + geom_boxplot()
bp + facet_grid(.~Species) + scale_fill_grey() + theme_classic()
```

How is this function meant to work? Looking at other examples I really can't see where I'm going wrong.

Thanks!

Edited to add data:

```
> dput(pond2)
structure(list(Species = c("AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC"
), Depth = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S"), 
    Length = c(123.82, 126.63, 136.28, 130.05, 140.8, 106.45, 
    137.6, 133, 145.16, 130.74, 127.1, 108.1, 106.87, 127.36, 
    101.82, 123.53, 132.28, 137.73, 97.47, 133.39, 116.38, 139.3, 
    130.35, 124.6, 132.18, 124.8, 138.35, 142.5, 139.11, 124.61, 
    138.52, 123.57, 103.17, 108.25, 110.8, 94.38, 115.61, 142.92, 
    133.98, 132.64, 132.46, 87.04, 130.19, 134.9, 135.48, 127.77, 
    106.56, 150, 150, 155, 160, 150, 155, 102.7, 77.62, 73.74, 
    96.95, 101.81, 105.06, 88.7, 109.37, 89.87, 109.4, 100.03, 
    83.78, 99.48, 85.2, 102.26, 88.92, 85.27, 69.42, 101.13, 
    132.64, 133.47, 102.01, 100.8, 145, 135.94, 127.9, 106.27, 
    137.17, 132.91, 117.34, 148.63, 145.21, 122.61, 134.38, 138.99, 
    118.45, 142.4, 138.98, 140.18, 150.24, 149.56, 141.46, 120.22, 
    149.61, 129.98, 140.88, 113.22, 111.33, 137.94, 100.52, 139.19, 
    132.47, 134.14, 127.09, 90.61, 122.26, 122.33, 96.52, 136.54, 
    139.73, 138.35, 130.9, 129.05, 133.81, 145.86, 115.81, 141.11, 
    111.38, 98.6, 136.74, 143.05, 141.76, 98.59, 116.42, 127.74, 
    137.61, 126.19, 139.68, 125.93, 135.26, 131.47, 143.83, 141.15, 
    128.14, 113.39, 132.42, 134.28, 129.76, 124.23, 127.38, 138.28, 
    148.09, 114.07, 131.49, 126.19, 125.63, 115.76, 155.6, 106.16, 
    133.86, 124.13, 133.4, 91.4, 104.57, 112.08, 111.21, 138.02, 
    98.22, 115.96, 136.41, 118.79, 108.4, 105.79, 110.4, 106.7, 
    66.22, 62, 68.59, 95.2, 103.12, 100.43, 118.5, 127.87, 131.73, 
    140.26, 109.12, 114.94, 103.36, 103.53, 101.87, 145.54, 121.36, 
    94.08, 129.47, 101.46, 104.59, 141.05, 149.93, 100.25, 143.55, 
    113.71, 117.93, 127.5, 104.75, 131.76, 100.38, 107.39, 151.42, 
    131.69, 142.3, 112.83), Breakage = c("N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
    "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
    "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
    "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
    "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y")), .Names = c("Species", 
"Depth", "Length", "Breakage"), row.names = c(NA, -204L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of `dput(pond2)` or, if the data frame is too big, of `dput(head(pond2, 30))` in the question?

Comment: You haven't specified how your data is mapped onto the fill aesthetic. (i.e. you need `aes(..., fill = Species)`)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like the following will do what you want.
First I make up some data, since you have not posted an example dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(6030)    # Make the results reproducible

pond2 <- data.frame(Species = sample(c("S1", "S2"), 100, TRUE),
                    Breakage = rep(c("yes", "no"), 50),
                    Length = runif(100, 10, 50))

bp <- ggplot(pond2, aes(x = Breakage, y = Length, fill = Species)) + geom_boxplot()
bp + facet_grid(. ~ Species) + scale_fill_grey() + theme_classic()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! With some tinkering I've worked out that it needed a fill term in the first line then the scale_fill_grey function (with hindsight this probably should have been obvious).
For anyone else's reference it now looks like this:
 bp <- ggplot(pond2, aes(x = Breakage, y = Length, fill=Species)) + geom_boxplot()
> bp + facet_grid(. ~ Species) + scale_fill_grey() + theme_classic()

Comment: @PrimroseMoss OK, I will edit the answer with `fill` instead of `colour`.